# Trying to isolate pt-query-digest per host

Tags: mysql, bash, percona, mysql-slow-query-log, pt-query-digest

I'm having some difficulty coming up with correct syntax to pull in specific host information for my slow query log file:

I'm using the following:

```
sudo pt-query-digest mysql-slow.log --since "2017-05-07 22:00:00" --until "2017-05-08 22:00:00" --filter ‘$event->{host} !~ m/^ip-1-1-1-1/’ > slow.log
```

In this scenario I'm trying to exclude all IPs that are 1.1.1.1. I can't figure out what's wrong.

Comment: The primary problem is with shell-processing, so I added a tag.

Comment: Shouldn't the pattern be `m/^1\.1\.1\.1$/`?

Answer (score 2):

Use ascii quote ('), not this non-ascii quote (‘);

Assuming that `m/^ip-1-1-1-1/` works, it will catch both `ip-1-1-1-1` and `ip-1-1-1-123`.  So you may need something to terminate the ip.  Perhaps `m/^ip-1-1-1-1$/`

Without hiding the arg in single-quotes, the shell is interpreting (at least) `$event` as a shell variable, `{...}` as something, and `!~` as something.